# "invalid next size" exception while reallocing memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, realloc

***P.S.:*** I have almost all questions for "invalid next size" but they are not helping me because I do not have another piece of code which malloc or realloc, so that is ruled out. Also, I am not assigning beyond the limits of memory space so I am fine on that front as well.

I have below code which is giving me - `*** Error in`./server_issue': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08249170 ***`.

I am not able to identify the problem, I am allocating just 64 bytes at a time so I am not out of memory address space and there is other memory allocation which could have possibly corrupted my heap memory.

Error says, invalid next size but as my last log tells `Reallocating 64 bytes, Aborted (core dumped)` so it means I am still trying to allocate 64 bytes. So, why error?

*For HTML file, have any file which is more than 256 bytes.*

**Code:** (minimum code to reproduce the issue)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char BYTE;
bool load(FILE*, BYTE**, size_t*);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("/home/university/psets/pset6/pset6_working/public/hello.html", "r");
    BYTE* content;
    size_t length;
    load(file, &content, &length);
}

bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
    int totalLength = 0;
    int readBytes = 0;
    *content = NULL;

    BYTE* fileContentTemp[64]; // working with 222222
    while ((readBytes = fread(fileContentTemp, 1, 64, file)) > 0)
    {
        printf("Reallocating %d bytes, ", readBytes);
        *content = realloc(*content, readBytes);
        printf("%p\n", *content);
        if(totalLength != 0)
        {
            memcpy(*content + totalLength + 1, fileContentTemp, readBytes);        
        } else{
            memcpy(*content + totalLength, fileContentTemp, readBytes);        
        }
        totalLength = totalLength + readBytes;
    }

    *length = totalLength;

    printf("CC image: %s\n", *content);
    printf("length is %d\n", *length);
    printf("fileContent %p\n", *content);

    return true;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Reallocating 64 bytes, 0x8249170
Reallocating 64 bytes, 0x8249170
*** Error in `./server_issue': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08249170 ***
Reallocating 64 bytes, Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

**Update:**
Even if I allocate 64 bytes instead of using `readBytes` while `realloc` then also I get the same error. I am getting error because of this line - `*content = realloc(*content, readBytes);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, I am not assigning beyond the limits of memory space so I am fine on that front as well.

Being overly sure of your code is a great way to make debugging more difficult. Suspect *everything* is wrong.

---

**You're not allocating enough memory, because you're using `realloc` incorrectly.**

`p = realloc(p, n)` doesn't *add* `n` bytes to the allocation, it changes the total allocation size to the size you tell it.

Each time through the loop you're passing `readBytes` which is the number of *additional* bytes you want to copy. So your buffer never grows. But then you proceed to write past the end of it:

```
memcpy(*content + totalLength, ...
```

as `totalLength` keeps growing throughout the loop.

---

Calling `realloc` in a loop like this is typically a bad idea performance-wise. You should allocate enough total space up-front, and then read into it in the loop.

To get the total file size:

```
size_t get_file_size(FILE *f)
{
    long oldpos;
    size_t result;

    // Save the original file position
    oldpos = ftell(f);

    // Seek to the first byte past the end of the file
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    // Get the file position - the number of bytes in the file
    result = ftell(f);

    // Return the file position to where it was
    fseek(f, oldpos, SEEK_SET);

    return result;
}
```

---

Here's a test, to demostrate what I am saying about `realloc`. Note, this uses `malloc_usable_size` which is bad practice, in general.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *p = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = realloc(p, 16);
        printf("[%d] size: %zd\n", i, malloc_usable_size(p));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o realloc realloc.c 
$ ./realloc 
[0] size: 24
[1] size: 24
[2] size: 24
[3] size: 24
[4] size: 24
[5] size: 24
[6] size: 24
[7] size: 24
[8] size: 24
[9] size: 24
```

Note that `malloc_usable_size()` returns the same value, even after multiple calls to `realloc` which pass the same size. Also, the fact that it returns 24, even though we allocated 16 bytes is expected, and is a result of implementation details of the allocator.

From the man page for `malloc_usable_size`:

> NOTES
>
> The value returned by malloc_usable_size() may be greater than the requested size of the allocation because of alignment and minimum size constraints.  Although the excess bytes can be overwritten by the application without ill effects, this is not good programming practice: the number of excess bytes in an allocation depends on the underlying implementation.
>
> The main use of this function is for debugging and introspection.

Comment: Even if I allocate 64 bytes instead of using `readBytes` then also I get the same error. I am getting error because of this line - `*content = realloc(*content, readBytes);`

Comment: Ok, I am fine with your `fseek` and `ftell` approach but I want to understand where I am doing wrong in my present code. Like I said my above comment, even if I use 64 then also it doesn't help .. My realloc looks fine because realloc with expand/shrink the existing pointer by specified size, now I want to expand it by 64/`readByte` each time so this looks ok to me .. And then I am starting from the location where last bytes was written so that also looks fine to me.. May you can explain more clearly what you want to explain on this front ..

Comment: "realloc with expand/shrink the existing pointer **by** specified size" Again, your understanding of `realloc` is incorrect. It changes the allocation size **to** the value given. It does not add to it. If you called `p = realloc(p, 10)` seven times, ther would still be only 10 bytes allocated. Not 70. In your code, this would involve passing `totalLength + readSize` to realloc. You have to tell it the total number of bytes you want.

Comment: You looks like an experienced guy so I have not many reasons to disbelieve you but this is what I read from `realloc` man page - "*The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes. .....*" .. It tell me that suppose I have a pointer for 10 bytes, when I call `realloc(ptr, 10)` then I will get 10 more bytes, and those new 10 memory location added to the end of last memory address of `ptr` will be uninitialized ..

Comment: Read it closely. *changes the size ... **to** `size` bytes.*

Comment: Ah, now I see. Perfect. Thank you so much for your inputs, time and actions on my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I added an example program which demonstrates the behavior I'm describing, so you can see it in action, as opposed to just text on a man page.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Why size is coming as 24, you allocated only 16? Something to do with data structure alligned memory size returned by `malloc_usable_size` ??

Comment: That was a good catch, have an upvote!  I upvote so rarely that I'm bookmarking this under 'miraculous' :(

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In the end of my `load` method if I try to close the file pointer then I get seg fault .. Any idea on that ??

Comment: You may still have memory issues somewhere. I would look into `valgrind`; it is a tool for detecting memory issues like these. It works really well if you compile you code with debug info (`gcc -g`).